# How can I ensure that docked Qt windows have visible controls with a dark platform theme?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Consider the following PyQt program,

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class dockdemo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dockdemo, self).__init__(parent)

        self.items = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Dockable", self)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItem("item1")
        self.listWidget.addItem("item2")
        self.listWidget.addItem("item3")

        self.items.setWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.items)
        self.setWindowTitle("Dock demo")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = dockdemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This works fine and produces a simple, docked window:

[image: Docked Qt window]

However, this isn't obeying my GTK2 dark platform theme. If I force Qt to do so by setting `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2`, I instead get this:

[image: Docked Qt window with dark platform theme]

The docked window's controls are almost the same colour as the background so they're very difficult to see.

GNU Octave in C++ shows its own docked widgets controls correctly in the platform theme:

[image: GNU Octave showing docked widgets with proper colours]

Octave's docked widgets also show the right controls when not using the system theme.

[image]

I suspect it's probably due to some of the CSS it's setting here, but I don't know exactly what: http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/6d0585c8ee11/libgui/src/octave-dock-widget.cc#l123

Am I doing something wrong? It feels like a bug that Qt isn't properly setting the colours for the docked window's controls unless you do something extra (and what that extra might be, I don't know yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to another answer here, I have a complete solution for my original problem as stated.

It appears that Qt simply hardcodes those icons without regard to the theme, but this is simple to fix.

First, we use the [relative luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance) to decide if a colour is bright or not,

```py
def is_dark(qt_colour):
    r, g, b = qt_colour.red(), qt_colour.green(), qt_colour.blue()
    luminance = (0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b)/256

    return luminance < 0.5
```

and then we grab some icons that are identical but coloured dark and light. I just grabbed Octave's own set of icons:

- [widget-close-light.svg](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/raw-file/9354d33dfbc4/libgui/src/icons/widget-close-light.svg)
- [widget-undock-light.svg](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/raw-file/9354d33dfbc4/libgui/src/icons/widget-undock-light.svg)
- [widget-close.svg](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/raw-file/9354d33dfbc4/libgui/src/icons/widget-close.svg)
- [widget-undock.svg](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/raw-file/9354d33dfbc4/libgui/src/icons/widget-undock.svg)

found in [its source tree](http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/9354d33dfbc4/libgui/src/icons). We place these icons in an `img/` subdirectory/subfolder.

Then, we grab the widget's background colour,

```py
        bg_colour = self.items.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Background)
```

and depending on that colour, we set the CSS to use the light or the dark set of icons:

```py
        if is_dark(bg_colour):
            self.items.setStyleSheet(
                """
                QDockWidget
                {
                  titlebar-close-icon: url(img/widget-close-light.svg);
                  titlebar-normal-icon: url(img/widget-undock-light.svg);
                }
                """
            )
        else:
            self.items.setStyleSheet(
                """
                QDockWidget
                {
                  titlebar-close-icon: url(img/widget-close.svg);
                  titlebar-normal-icon: url(img/widget-undock.svg);
                }
                """
            )
```

This results in proper icons in both light and dark themes!

[image: Light theme with docked widget and custom icons]
[image: Dark theme with docked widget and custom icons]

The complete code now looks like this:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


def is_dark(qt_colour):
    r, g, b = qt_colour.red(), qt_colour.green(), qt_colour.blue()
    luminance = (0.2126*r + 0.7152*g + 0.0722*b)/256

    return luminance < 0.5


class dockdemo(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dockdemo, self).__init__(parent)

        self.items = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Dockable", self)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItem("item1")
        self.listWidget.addItem("item2")
        self.listWidget.addItem("item3")

        self.items.setWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.items)
        bg_colour = self.items.palette().color(QtGui.QPalette.Background)
        if is_dark(bg_colour):
            self.items.setStyleSheet(
                """
                QDockWidget
                {
                  titlebar-close-icon: url(img/widget-close-light.svg);
                  titlebar-normal-icon: url(img/widget-undock-light.svg);
                }
                """
            )
        else:
            self.items.setStyleSheet(
                """
                QDockWidget
                {
                  titlebar-close-icon: url(img/widget-close.svg);
                  titlebar-normal-icon: url(img/widget-undock.svg);
                }
                """
            )
        self.setWindowTitle("Dock demo")


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = dockdemo()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That's a nice summary! If your app uses toolbar(s) with enough items to possibly have some of them hidden when the bar is too narrow/short, the next icons you'll need to deal with are `SP_ToolBarHorizontalExtensionButton` and/or `SP_ToolBarVerticalExtensionButton`  :-(  Luckily they have their [own class](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qtoolbarextension.cpp.html#_ZN17QToolBarExtension14setOrientationEN2Qt11OrientationE) so they should be easy to target in CSS with something like `QToolBar[orientation=1] QToolBarExtension { qproperty-icon: url(right.svg); }`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Linux-default Qt Fusion style dock icons are [hard-coded](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qfusionstyle.cpp.html#_ZNK12QFusionStyle12standardIconEN6QStyle14StandardPixmapEPK12QStyleOptionPK7QWidget) as XPM format images in the `QFusionStyle` (and also in `QCommonStyle` which is the fallback). And they are never colored to match the theme. A lot of the "standard" icons are like that but many are colored/opaque so the background doesn't make a big difference.

To override them you will need to either use CSS or a custom `QProxyStyle`.

You can see how it is done in CSS from that example you linked to.

```css
QDockWidget
{
  titlebar-close-icon: url(close.svg);
  titlebar-normal-icon: url(restore.svg);
}
```

A custom QStyle is a little more involved...

```cpp
class AppStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
  public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;

    QIcon standardIcon(StandardPixmap standardIcon, const QStyleOption *option = nullptr, const QWidget *widget = nullptr) const override
    {
      switch (standardIcon) {
        case SP_TitleBarNormalButton:
          return QIcon("restore.svg");

        case SP_TitleBarCloseButton:
        case SP_DockWidgetCloseButton:
          return QIcon("close.svg");

        default:
          return baseStyle()->standardIcon(standardIcon, option, widget);
      }
    }

    QPixmap standardPixmap(StandardPixmap stdPixmap, const QStyleOption *option = nullptr, const QWidget *widget = nullptr) const override
    {
      switch (stdPixmap) {
        case SP_TitleBarNormalButton:
        case SP_TitleBarCloseButton:
        case SP_DockWidgetCloseButton:
          return standardIcon(stdPixmap, option, widget).pixmap(option->rect.size());

        default:
          return baseStyle()->standardPixmap(stdPixmap, option, widget);
      }
    }

};
```

In both cases you'd need to know the theme being used somehow (eg. that it is dark). You'd use different (or dynamic) CSS for each theme, or your custom `QProxyStyle` would return the correct icon for the base color. In C++ for example you could even determine if the current palette background is dark (low color value) and then return different icons based on that.

P.S. Yes it could probably be considered a "bug" or deficiency that Qt doesn't handle this "automagically" already for dark system themes -- it is also quite annoying when trying to skin an app to be dark regardless of the desktop theme. But c'est la vie.

P.P.S. Whoops, just realized I gave a C++ example for a Python question... I don't use Python with Qt so I'm afraid that's the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot! I hadn't noticed that the Octave CSS simply ships its own icons and selects them based on the brightness of the background: 

http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/6d0585c8ee11/libgui/src/octave-dock-widget.cc#l449

I'm going to write a complete Python answer for my question based on the advice you've given me.

Comment: Ah, so this is the bug that prompted that fix in Octave: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?43837

Comment: Looks like Octave draws its own title bar entirely... but I didn't follow all the code.. it's hard to read. I did notice this warning in the Qt [CSS reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) under `QDockWidget`: "Warning: The style sheet has no effect when the QDockWidget is undocked as Qt uses native top level windows when undocked." Not sure what that means in practice in this particular issue (with dark system theme), TBH. Also perhaps useful is their [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qdockwidget) of styling `QDockWidget`.

Comment: Yeah, Octave has a custom widget. When it's undocked it's a top-level window (I can only tell this because my window manager draws it differently), which also lets it do something like showing a different icon to undock it. Anyway, thank you again so much for your help. I've written a complete answer to my original problem based on the help you gave me.